# How to create Oracle Database based on a relational scheme

Tags: database, oracle, inheritance

I am a beginner in Oracle databases.

I have a relational diagram and I want to create tables in Oracle, but I don't know how to make the relationships between them and the primary key at each. My teacher say that the tables "patients" and "doctors" have to inherit all the attributes from "Persons" table.

Also, the "prescription" table needs to inherit the attributes from "patients" and "doctors" table. So on with the "prescription" table.

This is the diagram

[image: diagram]

Comment: What have you tried so far ? We won't do your homework for you.

Comment: SO is not an "how-to" or a tutorial site. Start with some tutorial or with the [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/CREATE-TABLE.htm#SQLRF01402), try something and then, if you have an issue with your code, feel free to post it here and ask for help.

Comment: I tried to make tables in Oracle 11g with Object Browser and I don't know how to make the relationships between parents and childs (" Persons" like partents and "patients"and "doctors" like childs).

Comment: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/hjcv2pqb1cluati/18176106_1426294650765358_1966136478_o.png?dl=0]

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need you can find on this page: [official oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN11634)

Basic syntax of creating simple tables and inheritance of attributes in section "Parallelizing Table Creation".

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE empleat(

  emp_no number(6,0) CONSTRAINT fk_empleat PRIMARY KEY,

  nom varchar(20) CONSTRAINT nn_empleat_nom NOT NULL,

  cognom varchar(20),
  departament number(2,0) CONSTRAINT nn_empleat_dept NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE departament(
dept_no number(2,0) CONSTRAINT fk_departament_dept_no PRIMARY KEY,


nom varchar(20) CONSTRAINT nn_departament_nom NOT NULL,

localitat varchar2(30),

lider number(6,0) CONSTRAINT nn_departament NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why a doctor wouldn't have a date of birth or a gender so you could just merge the `people` and `patients` tables

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  id            NUMBER        CONSTRAINT people__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name    VARCHAR2(250) CONSTRAINT people__first_name__nn NOT NULL,
  last_name     VARCHAR2(250) CONSTRAINT people__last_name__nn NOT NULL,
  phone         VARCHAR2(20),
  date_of_birth DATE          CONSTRAINT people__date_of_birth__nn NOT NULL,
  gender        CHAR(1)       CONSTRAINT people__gender__chk CHECK ( gender IN ( 'M', 'F', 'X', 'Y' ) ),
  doctor        NUMBER        CONSTRAINT people__doctor__fk REFERENCES doctor ( id )
);

CREATE TABLE doctor (
  id             NUMBER        CONSTRAINT doctor__id__pk PRIMARY KEY
                               CONSTRAINT doctor__id__fk REFERENCES people ( id ),
  specialization VARCHAR2(250)
);
```

> My teacher say that the tables "patients" and "doctors" have to inherit all the attributes from "Persons" table.

If by this, they mean that the `doctors` table has to have all the columns of the `people` table then this breaks the idea of normalisation. If you are required to do this then it should be implemented as a `VIEW` rather than duplicating the data.

```
CREATE VIEW doctor_details IS
  SELECT p.*, d.sepcialization
  FROM   people p
         INNER JOIN
         doctors d
         ON ( p.id = d.id );
```

Comment: My teacher want to do what you said in second comm. That the 'doctors' table has to have all the columns of the 'people' table and the same thing on 'patients'. This is what I didn't understand until now. Thank you very much!

Comment: "Not sure why a doctor wouldn't have a date of birth or a gender " because those attributes are not relevant to DOCTOR entity (unless we are building an HR application) but they do have extreme relevance to medical treatments and so rightly belong to PATIENT entity